# Android : How to get large data above 20mb from server to android

Tags: android, web-services, bitmap

In my android application when a user login from a new device i want to download all his data from the server database that may be more than 20mb in size.This data include bitmap images that are converted to string.When a user uploads a image what i done so far is i just convert this image to bitmap and then convert it to string and then save this to database,after that this data will save to server database by syncing.If the same user login from a new device i need to take all those data from server with a webservice.Right now i am using resttemplate to load this data, but the problem is when there is more than 20mb of data that mainly contains some image data the webservice may take more time based on the image size.Is there any better way to deal with images??

Answer (score 1):

You can use aws s3. The images can be saved in the s3 buckets, which provides us with the URL. While loading all the details in the app instead of loading the whole image, only the s3 URLs needed to be send. The images can be downloaded later while loading them into the imageviews using libraries like  Picasso or glide.

Comment: looks like a nice thing.So i just need to save the url in my database and whenever  i need to use this image just pick it using url.Am i right??

Comment: can u show some examples..Also is this to be used for other files like pdf,documents,etc..

Comment: Yes. You can upload all types of files in s3 and retrieve it using the s3 urls

Comment: what is the difference bw s3 and glide?? what this s3 stands for?How should i search for this??

Comment: Aws s3 is a service provided by Amazon. Glide and Picasso are android libraries that you can use to download these images while loading them in their imageviews.

Comment: so instead of using aws s3 i can use glide to save images and load it using url provided glide??

Comment: No. S3 is a cloud based storage system. You can upload your images there. And they will provide you the download URLs. Glide usage comes in the app side. It is an android library to download these images seamlessly from the s3 storages servers.

Comment: that means we will loss the privacy of the file we are uploading.right??Do you know the mechanism that watsapp are using for showing the dp of peoples, even  if u dont have a net connection we can see the dp of our friend in the small imageview circle and when we need to see it in full screen need internet connection.How does it is poosible??

Comment: We can set privacy for each file too

Answer (score 1):

Do not use bitmap images (what ever you mean by it) but jpg's. Dont convert them to base64 as the amount of data will increase by 30%. Dont save them in a database on your server but on the server file system as normal files.

Then just give twenly urls for twenty files to the Android client and let the Android client decide when and how to download the images from url.

Alternatively you can let your base64 encoded images in the database. Just send twenty ids or file names (for twenty files) to the Android client. Then let the Android client decide when it wants to download an image using an url with parameter id.

Comment: how to save files in server and return the url of that file,and the file upload should happen with minimum time.

Comment: You can only ask a how to if you first tell what kind of server you have.

Comment: what u meant by what kind of server??

Comment: You have your own server with database. You use already one. Now tell what kind of server that is.

Comment: i have a server that can hold upto 100gb of data.

Comment: Nice for you. But i asked the kind/type of server. Not everybody uses the same technology.

Comment: we are using tomcat server

Comment: Ok. Well i cannot tell you how you would save an uploaded file to the file system of such a server. I wonder that you dont know how to do so where you are able to store an uploaded file in a database on it. Looks pretty elementary to me. But then maybe it is not possible. I dont know. Ask Tomcat. But you can still use the alternative.